# Why my mobile eats hell lot of wifi data

Tags: wi-fi, internet

I have a Micromax Canvas a200 turbo mini. I have started using WiFi since last month. In one month "Android OS" and Google Chrome have used 63 GB of WiFi data. I have tried using third party apps, but they are only useful when you are using cellular data. I have tried reset factory as well.

What would cause this high data usage?

[image: data usage screenshot]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can try opera max. It is VPN service that having app management features. There you can manage which app to allow network connections. And then only allowed apps would be able to access network bandwidth.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer to the question, I second this suggestion. Opera Max will let you know in detail everything related to data and WiFi usage. You can block access to Internet for certain apps, too.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I know why an OS would use a lot of data connection is downloading upgrades. Did your phone install (a) lot of system updates recently? Are you using stock firmware or did you install a custom OS like [CynogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/), possibly even a [nightly build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_build) that updates every night?

For Chrome data usage there may be a lot of reasons - it usually completely depends on what you do with your browser. If you download large files, for example, that would be counted as Chrome data usage, too. Also watching videos or complete movies via browser will be accounted as usage for Chrome.

Maybe you might want to try [3g watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog), which is a very good app for traffic supervision that I use for 2 years now - perhaps that would split the individual system components using wifi data better.

Comment: Hey david, One thing i forgot to mentioned, that all data are used in background by chrome, as i am pretty sure i have not used such files downloading or heavy surfing of 18GB. Apart from that, i was using normal inbuilt OS without any change, and there is no update available to download for that. This is where its confusing and irritating.

Comment: Does the problem only occur on wifi or on mobile connection, too? Did you try scanning your phone with a virus scanner yet?